# AG-Grid React, trouble getting custom cell renderer to update when data changes. Function components are behaving differently than class components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, cellrenderer

I'm using AG-Grid throughout a react application, and in several instances I want a cellRenderer to update when grid data changes. In both of the following cases, the cellRenderer loads correctly initially, but doesn't update when data changes:

1. A user edits an editable cell and changes the value.
2. The server updates the grid data in redux

Check out this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cell-renderer-demo-4ypyv?file=/src/index.js)

In this example I recreated the first use case with an editable cell, and used a class component and a function component. Using onCellValueChanged with params.api.refreshCells() I was able to get the class component to update, but not the function component.

First question: How do I get react function components to re-render with new props, the same way the class component re-renders in the codesandbox example?

Second question: Is there a better way to update a cellRenderer without un-mounting and re-mounting every cell in the column any time data updates?

Thanks in advance for the help and guidance!

```
...
    this.state = {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: "Editable Country",
          editable: true,
          field: "country",
          width: 200
        },
        {
          headerName: "Class Render",
          cellRendererFramework: GridCellClass,
          colId: "class-renderer",
          width: 200
        },
        {
          headerName: "Function Render",
          cellRendererFramework: GridCellFunction,
          colId: "function-renderer",
          width: 200
        }
      ],
      rowData: []
    };
  }

...

            <AgGridReact
              rowModelType="infinite"
              columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
              enableColResize={true}
              rowClassRules={{
                california: function(params) {
                  return params.data.country === "California";
                }
              }}
              onCellValueChanged={function(params) {
                return params.api.refreshCells({
                  force: true,
                  columns: ["class-renderer", "function-renderer"]
                });
              }}
              onGridReady={this.onGridReady.bind(this)}
              rowData={this.state.rowData}
            />
...
```

```
// This one updates!
import React, { Component } from "react";

class GridCellClass extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        {data.country === "California" ? "CALIFORNIA!!!" : "Not California"}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GridCellClass;
```

```
// This one does not update.
import React from "react";

function GridCellFunction(props) {
  const { data } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      {data.country === "California" ? "CALIFORNIA!!!" : "Not California"}
    </div>
  );
}

export default GridCellFunction;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.**Cell Renderer Function**

A cell renderer function should be used when you dont have refresh requirements and this is mentioned in the ag-grid docs.

As per [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#cell-renderer-function)-

> Use the function variant of a cell renderer if you have no refresh or
>   cleanup requirements (ie you don't need to implement the refresh or
>   destroy functions).

This is the reason why your cell renderer function does not refresh.

To solve your problem, you can do this -

```
      onCellValueChanged={function(params) {
        if(params.column.getId() === 'country') {
          params.api.redrawRows();
        }
      }}
```

2.**Cell Renderer Component**

The reason your `GridCellClass` works on `api.refreshCells()` is because the grid handles the `refresh()` for you since you have not implemented `refresh()` in your `GridCellClass` component.

What that means is your component will be destroyed and recreated if the underlying data changes.

3.**RefreshCells**

Also note that using `api.refreshCells()` won't work as is because ag-grid uses change detection to refresh cells while determining what cells to refresh and since essentially the value of your other 2 columns do not change but infact they are changed in the cellRenderer itself.

However the below works for `GridCellClass` because you disable change detection by passing `force:true`,

```
       params.api.refreshCells({
          force: true
        });
```

From docs-

> Change detection will be used to refresh only cells who's display cell
>   values are out of sync with the actual value. If using a cellRenderer
>   with a refresh method, the refresh method will get called.

Comment: redrawRows works for both, that’s great. Adding a refresh method in GridCellClass seems like a better idea that won’t cause unnecessary remounts. I found examples of refresh methods being used in class components, but couldn’t find any for function components. Do you know if that’s supported?

Comment: Refresh is not supported in functions as I mentioned in the answer as well as in the docs - Use the function variant of a cell renderer if you have no refresh or cleanup requirements (ie you don't need to implement the refresh or destroy functions).

Comment: Got it. I can see that being an issue if I want to use react hooks inside the cell renderer component, the component would need to be a function not a class. It’s still a react component, not a “simple function”. The docs say it requires getGui()

Comment: "params.api.refreshCells({ force: true });" works!!!